# Django a way to store user-level data

Tags: django

I'm looking for an efficient way to store some **user-level data** that do not need to be persistent.

For example, I would like to show user a **different** error message when user encounters **the same error more than once**.
Right now I generate a user-unique key and then add it to the **cache system**.

I first thought to store it in the **user session**, but it is stored in database and I don't need it to be stored there. It's ok if this data will be lost on server restart/shutdown.

May be there is a better solution for such cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session is the right place. If you don't want to use the database, then don't use a database session backend.

Comment: Really, I forgot that I can set separate session store.